# How I can show only three elements of my associative array using for?

Tags: php

This is my Associative Array:

```
$vetor = array(
 "Name"=> "myName",
 "Tel"=> "555-2020",
 "Age"=> "60",
 "Gender"=> "Male"
);
```

How I can show only three elements using the loop `for`?

I tried this:

```
for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){
 echo $vetor[$i]."<br>";            
}
```

But without success. How I can do this?

Comment: Does it have to be a `for` loop for this homework, or can it be a `foreach`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Appears the error: `Undefined offset: 0`, Undefined offset: 1....`

Comment: The `foreach` displays ALL content of `array`. I don't want this. I want display only three results.

Comment: If my `array` has 200 elements and I use a `foreach`, it will display all 200 elements. Say I want display only 120.. Understand me?

Comment: @LuizSantos - Understand what you're saying, but you're incorrect: you can use foreach over only part of an array -  `foreach(array_slice($vetor, 0, 3) as $value) {...}`

Comment: Yea I know you will be getting errors, I was just checking whether you HAD to use a for loop

Comment: As long as you know which element you want to use and they are in nice congiguous blocks @MarkBaker suggestion is good. However if you want to use occurances `1,9 27,54,72,.....` then its going get messy however you eventually code it

Comment: This is not a homework hahaha I am studying self-taught way to expand my knowledge as dev. And this was a curiosity. The exemple of @Burimi solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You referring to wrong indexes because to reference the first element on your array you have to do something like : $vetor["Name"] instead of $vetor[0]

```
$i = 0;
foreach($vetor as $key => $value){
   if($i == 2){ break; }
   echo $value;
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: This is sort of what I was getting at when I made [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190864/how-i-can-show-only-three-element-of-my-associative-array-using-for?noredirect=1#comment61914382_37190864)

Comment: It was exactly what I was wondering how to make, because if I have a 100, 200,300 elements.. I just change the `$i` and so I can display the amount that I want. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` makes more sense for an array like this, but if you want to use `for` for whatever reason, the problem you'll have is that the array doesn't have sequential numeric indexes that correspond to your loop increment variable. But there are other ways to iterate over the first three elements without knowing what the indexes are.

```
// this first step may not be necessary depending on what's happened to the the array so far
reset($vetor);

$times = min(3, count($vetor));

for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
    echo current($vetor).'<br>';
    next($vetor);
}
```

If `next` moves the internal array pointer beyond the last array element, `current($vetor)` will return `false`, so setting `$times` using `min` with the number of times you want and the array count will prevent you from looping more times than there are items in the array.

---

Another way, if you don't care what the keys are, is to use `array_values` to convert the array keys to numbers.

```
$vetor = array_values($vetor);
for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    echo $vetor[$i].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: These are other ways to also let safe here hahah, thank you! A question: To print the associative arrays I always have to convert array keys to numbers?

Comment: If you want to use `for` rather than `foreach` on an array with string keys (or non-consecutive numeric keys), converting the keys to numbers is one way to do it. In the first example, the keys are not converted, and you can access them within the loop using the `key` function. Generally, it's easier to just use `foreach`, though. :)

Comment: I didn't know the power of the `foreach`. Very good! Thank you!